# Switch Windows in Ubuntu Using Keyboard

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Does anybody have any idea whether it is possible to switch between Windows in Ubuntu using the keyboard? I don't mean pressing Alt-Tab, but rather some key combination that switches to the first window, second window, etc. It is annoying to have to move your hard to the mouse many times when you have sometime routine task that you want to apply to all windows.

Also, any idea if this is possible under Windows?

Thanks,
Rafid

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 TLS

I will create Launcher shortcuts (on left side bar) for my most common applications

so I can use `super + [Number]` combination key to open the application if that not running, or switch to the application if it already running.

Hope my anwser is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find ways for windows [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449).
Additionally you can use [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) for ubuntu keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+ the number of the tab (reading from left to right). For example, for the third tab, Alt+3, for the fifth tab Alt+5, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab

Comment: Read it carefully: "I don't mean pressing Alt-Tab, but rather some key combination that switches to the first window, second window, etc."